# how change textbox text after clicking on a button inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have one textbox and one button both on a gridview , when user clicks on button i want to get the textbox text and save to database then clear the text! i used code below it works fine and saves to database but cant clear the textbox why ?

```
     protected void sendcm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button sendcm = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)sendcm.NamingContainer;
            int ActivityTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(activity.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["ActivityTypeID"].ToString());
            int SourceID = Convert.ToInt32(activity.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["SourceID"].ToString());

   TextBox tt = (TextBox)activity.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].FindControl("cmtextbox");
                if (tt.Text != "")
                {
                    BusinessLayer.StatusComment_Table ncm = new BusinessLayer.StatusComment_Table();
                    ncm.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
                    ncm.Statusid = SourceID;
                    ncm.Statuscommentdate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    ncm.Statuscommenttext = tt.Text;
                    ncm.Save();
                    tt.Text = ""; // its not working !!!!
                }

}
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SessionLable.Text = Session["ID"].ToString();


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getData();
    }
}
```

---

```
     public void getData()
    {

   activity.DataSource = BusinessLayer.Activity_Table.GetByProfileData(ID, -1, activity.PageSize);

                activity.DataBind();



        }
```

Comment: Are you rebinding your gridview on post back?  What's happening in your page_load?

Comment: textbox1.text=string.Empty; use this after binding your gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this to solve my problem !

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="cmtextbox" type="text" clientid="cmtextbox" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="نظر دهید..." Rows="1" style="resize:none"  class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="sendcm" style="margin-top:2px;"    OnClick="sendcm_Click" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left " OnClientClick="ClearTextbox(this)"  runat="server" Text="ارسال" />   



  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ClearTextbox = function (that) {
            $(that).prevUntil('div.stop', '[ClientID="cmtextbox"]').val('');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is very much inline with my suggestion. I am glad you figured it out. -Judson

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this at the UI level.

Use jquery.post to call the method that saves the data.

return something back to the $.post callback to tell jquery that the post s complete,

then do something like $('#mytextfield').val('')

assuming that the text box has an ID. I am assuming this is HTML?

Comment: this way will clear all textboxes , but i only want to clear on of them !

Comment: $('#mytextfield').val('') only clears the specific textbox with that ID. You can auto generate the ids of each of the textboxes by passing an id into the markup id="someIdVariable" or in a loop create auto incrementing variables for IDS. If you need more than this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to rebind your grid because from the code that you posted it's not clear that where are you re binding your grid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable AjaxPostback in your page. After that, in your Page_Load logic, include the code

```
if(IsPostBack){...}else{...}
```

So you can handle the construction of UI elements depending on whether this is a fresh new view of the page or a postback (page refreshed due to user clicking the button). UI elements are sent to the browser, after that, there is no way for the server to change it except to refresh the page itself.

The manual (and the one I recommend) way is to do this via jQuery postback. As pointed out in the other answer, you'll need to setup an endpoint for the client browser to connect. After the server has done its job, return the result to the client. Then use jQuery to update the textbox.